# How to dynamically allocate a partial view within a parent view with Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, handlebars.js, sammy.js

I'm somewhat new to both web app development and the Handlebars & Sammy frameworks, so excuse me if this is a somewhat obvious question.

I have created a main view template for pages that look like this:

```
<article id="imageWrapper">
    <img src="{{img.url}}" alt="{{img.title}}" />
</article>
<article id="pageContent">
    {{> page}}
</article>
```

where `page` would be my partial view. I am trying to achieve a solution to the following:

I have several different page-types (like a grid-like gallery, some text-only pages etc.), but they all follow this general layout. Instead of copying and pasting these code fragments into x amounts of sub page views, I'd like to create a "master view" that all sub-views "inherits" from - so that both my gallery views and text views have the same outer structure, but still can have their own sub-views specified somewhere else.

I am using the JS-framework [Sammy](http://sammyjs.org/) to handle the creation of these views, but as far as I could understand from their [API documentation](http://sammyjs.org/docs/api/0.7.1/all), the framework does not have a `Render` or `Partial` method that deals with my situation (being able to specify both a parent view and child view).

Am I missing something, or do I have to do it the "not-so-cool" way?

Answer (score 0):

Let me allow myself to answer my own question - for future beginners. Took me some time to figure it out, but now everything works like it should.

Sammy's `Render`-method actually takes an object holding key-value pairs of partial view names (keys) and the path to the partial view (value) after the data itself. My implementation ended up looking like this:

```
context.render('templates/contentPage.hb', item, {subView: 'templates/textView.hb'});
```

The subView-string is simply changed between routes, but can also be changed dynamically for one route (obviously) if that's your situation. To include your partial view, simply mention it in the partial view syntax in your template:

```
{{>subView}}
```

and it will be included as it should.